# Save strings from for loop to an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to get substrings from a string (a=ATCG) and then store it in an array but I am getting a warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
 dna[i]=dna1;

I want the output array to print: 
ATCG
TCG
CG
G

I am new to C, how do I fix this?

Here's my program

```
int main()
{
    char a[]="ATCG", dna[20], *dna1  ;

    dna1 = (char *)malloc(2000);
    int i, len_of_seg_2;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        len_of_seg_2=strlen(a)-i+1;  
        strncpy(dna1, a+i, len_of_seg_2); 
        dna1[len_of_seg_2-1]='\0';

        dna[i]=dna1;
        printf("sequence:%s\n",dna1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("\nseq:%s\n",dna[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `dna1` is `char *`, `dna[i]` is `char`. The error is exactly what it says. You are assigning a pointer to an integer value. Maybe you meant `dna[i] = *dna1`? Also, remember to `free(dna1)` for good practice.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the statement `dna[i]=dna1;`? Are you trying to copy a single character, or a string. If you are trying to copy a string, then why is the destination (`dna[i]`) a character?

Comment: I am trying to copy the entire string. In the statement dna [i]=dna1; I am trying to store dna1 as element number i in the dna array. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a '*' infront of `dna[20]`.

```
int main()
{
    char a[]="ATCG";
    char *dna[20];  // <-- this was char dna[20]
    char *dna1;

    dna1 = (char *)malloc(2000);
    int i, len_of_seg_2;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        len_of_seg_2=strlen(a)-i+1;  
        strncpy(dna1, a+i, len_of_seg_2); 
        dna1[len_of_seg_2-1]='\0';

        dna[i]=dna1;  // <-- this was the crash
        printf("sequence:%s\n",dna1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("\nseq:%s\n",dna[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/ZhO3SZ

Comment: It prints from the first for loop. However I am trying to print it out from the second for loop so that I can access the stored subsequences elsewhere in the code. From the second for loop it only prints the last subsequence, G. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

the type of `dna1` is `char *`, and the type of `dna[i]` is `char`. The error is exactly what it says. You are assigning a pointer (dna1) to an integer value (dna[i]). You can't do that - actually, you can and you did, which is why you saw this warning - without explictly telling the compiler that you want to do it (`dna[i] = (char)dna1;` in this case). Maybe you meant `dna[i] = *dna1?`. I don't know what you want to do.

Also, remember to `free(dna1)` for good practice.